# How to hide work flow action?

Tags: workflow

I created 2 Workflows. while creating two workflows I am able to see all actions, But while creating Third workflow I am not able to see task assign. what happend. how can hide action in workflow.

Comment: What do you mean by how to hide workflow action? Can you rephrase your quetion or add screenshot?

Comment: This is one Interview question. He asked me that while creating workflow only three actions were there. what happened & how can some one hide the workflow action.

Comment: You can try what your interviewer asked you. If you actually face any issue, please post back the details of your query.

Comment: not all objects support activities (tasks)

Comment: yaaa you are right crop. becoz of you I came to know that we cannot perform all workflow actions to all objects. like user don't have "assign task" and Task don't have "send Email"...... ect....     Thank you very much